# Elementor Mailerlite Integration - Group limit

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I recently found out that Elementor has a limit of 100 groups when using the Mailerlite functionality. We have over 200 groups. The functions that is responsible for this is located under: plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/classes/mailerlite-handler.php

I added the line: $results = $this->rest_client->get( 'groups?limit=250' ); and that fixes the issue, but on the next update it will go away.

Can someone please help and tell me if there is a better way of doing it then this? Thank you!

```
/**
 * get MailerLite groups associated with API key
 * @return array
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function get_groups() {
    //$results = $this->rest_client->get( 'groups' );
    $results = $this->rest_client->get( 'groups?limit=250' );

    $groups = [
        '' => esc_html__( 'Select...', 'elementor-pro' ),
    ];

    if ( 200 === $results['code'] ) {
        foreach ( $results['body'] as $index => $group ) {
            $groups[ $group['id'] ] = $group['name'];
        }
    }

    $return_array = [
        'groups' => $groups,
        'fields' => $this->get_fields(),
    ];

    return $return_array;
}
```

Comment: This is a question for the Elementor team. Reach out to them and ask whether there's a filter hook you could use to raise the limit so you don't have to modify plugin's code.

Comment: I'm not the 1st to ask this issues. It was asked on there support also but nobody ever answered.